# Strange issue with mysqli_stmt_bind_result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Alright so this bugs the crap out of me, and I can't seem to find anything in the PHP documentation, nor anywhere in the Google resultosphere, so maybe someone can help here.

I am using prepared statements, binding the results, and then using those bound results to populate dropdown. Example:

```
<option value="">Select artist</option>
<?php   
    $artistQuery = "SELECT ArtistID,ArtistName FROM Artist_v";
    if($artist = mysqli_prepare($link,$artistQuery)){
        mysqli_stmt_execute($artist);
        $artistResult = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($artist,$artistID,$artistName);

        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($artist)){
?>
<option value="<?php echo $artistID; ?>"><?php echo $artistName; ?></option>
<?php
        }
        mysqli_stmt_close($artist);
    }
?>
<option value="Other">Add new...</option>
```

There is something you might notice is a little odd. Namely:

```
$artistResult = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($artist,$artistID,$artistName);
```

In the [PHP documentation for mysqli_stmt_bind_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) there is no reason whatsoever to capture this result into a variable, that something like this should be just fine:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($artist,$artistID,$artistName);
```

Not only that, the variable that I use to capture the result is never used. The only reason I capture at all is because without performing this capture **processing always fails**. Like ... the rest of the page refuses to even be produced. I've checked `mysqli_error()`, `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');`, all the error messaging you can think of ... nothing.

What's worse, my development box doesn't have this issue, nor did my previous hosting provider ... I encountered this first when I changed to my new provider. This tells me (a) my original PHP is just fine, and (b) it could be a settings / options issue. I just have no idea where.

Has anyone experienced this?

By the way, don't ask me how I arrived at the variable capture thing to get it working ... it was a multi-hour trial-and-error session, and I couldn't tell you what my thinking was for trying it.

Comment: Can you explain "there is no reason whatsoever to capture this result into a variable ... and as you can see in my resulting PHP, it never uses it."

Comment: sure, i'll mod my answer.

Comment: Mighty weird. So, just omitting `$artistResult = ` = crash and burn?

Comment: @Wrikken yes! it works fine on my dev box (localhost) and it was working fine on my old provider. I copy and paste the code ... splat. the weirdest damn thing.

Comment: If you isolate it in a test file (no includes, no other code), just a connect, prepare, execute, and bind: does that still exhibit that behavior?

Comment: yup ... actually that was the beginning of the multi-hour journey i referred to. i get a 500 error. and before you ask ... no access to `/var/log`, im on shared hosting. :(

Comment: You have 2 selects and 3 binds - `SELECT ArtistID,ArtistName` - `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($artist,$artistID,$artistName)` in my experiences, that would not show me anything. Why, I have no idea.

Comment: `$artist` is the mysqli statement executed, and the 2 following are the variable names that the SELECT returns. this is standard for the procedural based on the PHP documentation.

Comment: i also just tested it using the OO style, same result.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Even shared hosting should give you access to your own error logs. Are you using CPanel or similar? The key to solving this puzzle lies there

Comment: i do use cPanel, im actually on chat with support right now. if i have access to my own logs, i have no idea where they would be! guidance?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea It's been a while since I used CPanel but the error logs used to be available from the main dashboard page, near the bottom. Also see http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/ErrorLog

Comment: ah yeah i found where you mean. all it says, though, is that my 500.shtml file doesnt exist. it doesnt actually tell me what the error is.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Ignore that, there will be something else triggering the initial 500 error

Comment: naw i mean the output from the last 20 minutes from all the reloads is the exact same ... for each attempt it cant find the 500.stml, the favicon.ico, or the 404.shtml. there literally are no other errors listed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this really isn't a bloody answer, but my problem has been solved.

Turns out that the implementation of version 5.4 is sh**ty or something, because I switched to having my site run off of version 5.3 and all of a sudden it worked.

Bottom line, I appreciate all the help that you guys offered, but I must force myself to use an older version of PHP for the time being at least. That's four days I'll never get back.

**EDIT**

I found a real solution: switch hosting providers. Haven't experienced this issue since.

Comment: Have you made it work without assigning it to a variable? I'm experiencing the same issue but I have tried assigning it to a variable but I couldn't get it to work. Eg. `mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $photo_id)` and it doesn't assign the value to `$photo_id`. I have made the query in the mysql and it worked.