# mysqli_stmt_bind_result not returning a value

Tags: php, mysqli

Alright so this bugs the crap out of me, and I can't seem to find anything in the PHP documentation, nor anywhere in the Google resultosphere, so maybe someone can help here.

I'm trying to make a simple request to a database to return a `varchar(30)`.

Code:

```
$qryID = "select idPhotos from housesphotos where idHouse = ?";
//Prepare the query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $qryID);

$x = 106;
 //Bind the login parameter to the statement
if(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $x)){
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        //Bind every column in the select
        if(mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $photoID)){
//                $photoID = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
            echo $photoID;
        }
    }
}

if(empty($photoID)){
    printf("EMPTY");
}
```

As you can guess the output was `EMPTY`. I have tried using this solution: [Strange issue with mysqli_stmt_bind_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438282/strange-issue-with-mysqli-stmt-bind-result/19439787#comment74793920_19439787) but it did not work.

To make sure that everthing was suppost to go correctly I have made the query in the mysql and it worked wonders:

```
select idPhotos from housesphotos where idHouse = 106
```

OUTPUT:

```
591219e92b2fe_591219e92b302
```

The `housephotos` is a `varchar(30)` field. I'm not sure if it's the field type that is messing with the return value. I'm not sure also if it's the connections that I made earlier on the code but I have tried `unset($stmt)` and other variables to solve the problem but it's not working.

Is this some kind of bug with `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` or just a new person's mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually *fetching* the results - you commented the `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` out. The fetch also returns a boolean, not the actual results. Uncomment that line, and remove the variable assignment to it.

```
$qryID = "select idPhotos from housesphotos where idHouse = ?";
//Prepare the query
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $qryID);

$x = 106;
 //Bind the login parameter to the statement
if(mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $x)){
    if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        //Bind every column in the select
        if(mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $photoID)){
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt); // Remove the comment and variable assignment
            echo $photoID;
        }
    }
}
```

If you still don't get any results, it might be because the number of rows returned was zero (you can check that with `$stmt->num_rows` after executing), but since you said the query worked in phpMyAdmin, it's likely that there's some sort of error you're ignoring. To check for errors, add an `else` to your `if` conditions, and log `$stmt->error` inside.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 1):

It seems that PHP 5.4 (at least the way it's installed on Comcast servers) has a bug that causes bind-result to fail on a varchar field. Changing the field definition to "text" solves the problem.